# Autoclose HTML tags in Sublime

Tags: sublime-text-3, sublime-text

If I hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> at `<div`, it autocloses: `<div>|<\div>`.

`|` represents the cursor.

However, when I type `<div cla` and hit those keys, Sublime turns it into  `<div class="|">`.

Is there anyway to make it `<div class="">|</div>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> on OS X), to *Wrap selection in tag* rather than writing the tag manually first.

You first get:

```
<p></p>
 └── cursor
```

Then you can write your tag name, e.g. `div`, then hit <kbd>Space</kbd> and write an attribute name (even with auto-completion).

```
<div class="_"></div>
            └── cursor
```

You can now enter attribute values, then press <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>, and end up inside the tag:

```
<div class="foo">_</div>
                 └── cursor
```

If you press <kbd>Tab</kbd> only once though, you can enter an additional attribute.

Comment: I found it is Alt-Shift-W on Linux (yours is Mac).  Anyways thanks for the help